# How to use oracle Wallet and .net web api

Tags: .net, oracle, asp.net-web-api, wallet

I am using oracle wallet for log-in into Oracle 11 DB instance, from my .net Web API 2 code.

problem is unless I specify the user ID and password in connection string , oracle wallet throws

```
Error MessageORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

which doesn't justify use of wallet! 
I have googled much yet not much luck with any possible solution.

**sqlnet.ora**

```
sqlnet.authentication_services=(NTS)
ssl_client_authentication=false
WALLET_LOCATION=
(SOURCE=
 (METHOD=FILE)
 (METHOD_DATA=
     (DIRECTORY=c:\temp\wallet)
 )
)
```

**Tnsnames.ora**

```
source= (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=<PROTOCOL>)(HOST=<server hostname>)PORT=<PORT>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<Global DB Name>)))
```

my **web.config** file reads the specific section as below - this way connection fails with aforesaid error

```
<settings>
<setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\ORA\TNSFILES"/>
<setting name="WALLET_LOCATION" value="(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=c:\temp\wallet)))"/>
<setting name="SSL_VERSION" value= "0" />
<setting name="SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION" value = "TRUE" />
</settings>

<connectionStrings>
<add name="OracleWallet1" providerName="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"     connectionString="Data Source=source;User Id=/;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

please suggest what could be the issue here

Comment: I have tried adding the below combinations onto sqlnet.ora as well  - still the same 'SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE'
'SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE'
'SSL_VERSION = 0'

Answer (score 0):

In the latest ODP.NET 12.2 documentation, [more detailed information](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT8269) on steps to configure managed ODP.NET with TLS/SSL with wallets is available. If you are still encountering an error, I would recommend opening a service request with Oracle Support and providing traces from both the client and server side. Using wallets is largely a configuration exercise. The traces make it easier to identify if some setting is misconfigured or a step was missed. Since the trace information is very detailed, it is NOT recommended you place this information on SO or anywhere else on the public internet.

Comment: Thanks for the response , your suggestion to use 12.2 seems to be only way forward in my case. I just came to know about the Oracle bug "BUG 19261209 - FILE WALLET WITH MANAGED ODP.NET PROVIDER FAILS WITH ORA-01017" , So in Oracle 11 version  ..When creating a .net application that is configured to use the
Oracle wallet (file based), setup up the connection to the database fails with ORA-1017: invalid Login.

Comment: I don't think it's bug 19261209. That bug was fixed in 2015. The fix should be part of any managed ODP.NET 12.1 released in the last year and a half.

Nonetheless, I would still encourage your to use ODP.NET 12.2, simply to ensure you are not hitting another known issue that is already fixed.